# Server Not Working With Jumbo MTUs

Tags: mtu

I am a network engineer & my server guy doesn't appear to be able to get the jumbo MTU's to work on his NIC team. We are using LACP for two 10gig interfaces between the switch. I am 100% certain that the switch is configured for jumbo frames. And to visually see it, I have tested it using pings at 9100 size and the df-bit set to that switch and it works. However, his servers just don't seem to work with 8k pings to that same switch. Are there any settings with the port-channel on the server that he can use to fix the problem? I'm certain the switch isn't an issue.

Comment: I don't understand  if you have set the jumbo frame on your nic server also.

Comment: He said that he has

Comment: Is the server a LNX machine? 
if yes could you post an ifconfig <interface name> output and ethtool -i <interface name> output?

Comment: also ...ethtool -S <interface name>